# How to extract words from a sentence using two while loops?

Tags: arrays, c, string

I want to go through a sentence and convert each word in it to pig latin, while also preserving the punctuation. Here is the code I'm using:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){
  char input[100];
  int arraypos=0;
  int ch;
  char word[100];

  
  char output[200]={'\0'};
  while ((ch=getchar())!='\n'){
          input[arraypos]=ch;
      arraypos++;
    }
    input[arraypos]='\0';


    int j=0;
    int index=0;
    char punct[1];
   while (input[j]!='\0'){
      while(!(isspace(input[j]))&&(!(ispunct(input[j])))){
    word[index]=input[j];
    index++;
    j++;
      }
      word[index]='\0';
      strcat(output, piglatin(word));
      punct[0]=input[j];
      punct[1]='\0';
      strcat(output,punct);
      index=0;
      j++;
   } 
    
     printf("%s\n", output);
}
```

I am sure that the piglatin function used here works . The problem is with looping through this sentence and working with it.

If I remove the first while loop:

```
while (input[j]!='\0'){
```

then if the I enter: `Hello,my name is Michael` the output is `Ellohay,` ( which is correct).
However, if I add the same while loop to make it work for each word. It gives me a segmentation fault.

Comment: `main.c:21:5: error: ‘word’ undeclared (first use in this function)` ???

Comment: @BobJarvis-ReinstateMonica I declared word as global variable,will include that here.

Comment: Just one thing i saw directly. You are initializing punct as a array of size one. Later you access punct[1] which is out of bounds.

Comment: @moritz when i declare punct[1] , won't there be 2 spaces. So punct[0] and punct[1]?

Comment: No. You have to initialize an array with its size. For two spaces you would write `char array[2];` You can just google, there are pletty of examples. To be honest i don't really know what a compiler does if you are initializing an array with 0. But you can't generally rely on any behavoir.

Answer (score 1):

The `j++;` line appears 2 times inside the while loop.

Because of that, probably you are skipping the '\0' character at the end of the "input" array, and the `while (input[j]!='\0')` continues after the end of the array.

To solve it, try to fill the "input" array with '\0' in the begging of the function, right after declaring it. Use:

```
memset(input, '\0', 100);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in inner while loop as Fabio mentioned.
So your code should go like this:

```
while(!(isspace(input[j])) && (!(ispunct(input[j]))) && input[j+1] != '\0')
{
    word[arraypos] = input[j];
    ++arraypos;
    ++j;
}
```

When you come to the last word, your inner loop goes after the end of array because you don't check for '\0', you just check for spaces and punctuations which can happen if you don't enter it in the sentence so while loop goes on. In this case I used pre-increment, because pre-increment is faster than post-increment because post-increment keeps a copy of previous value and adds 1 in the existing value while pre-increment is simply adds 1 without keeping the existing value.

Comment: And also you should initialize char punct[1] to char punct[2] because you are storing 2 chars in it. As you said about in comments punct[0] and punct[1] so there are 2 positions/elements in it.

Comment: this seems to work, but now my output is slightly different then what is should be. Now 'Hello, my name is Michael ' is outputting to Ellohay, ymay amenay Ichaemayl. The last Michael should be Ichaelmay. The rules are if the word starst with a vowel then you add yay to the end, if it doesnt start with a vowel you find the first vowel, take the letter before the vowel and add it to the end, and add ay.

Comment: Than you have problem in your piglatin function.. because if you put strcat(output, word) instead of strcat(output, piglatin(word)) it will print words as you entered them. That indicated that problem is probably in the piglatin function somewhere and we can't see the function.